# Blurry Transformed Text in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, blurry, drawingcontext, formatted-text

I'm using `DrawingContext.DrawText` and `DrawingContext.PushTransfrom` to create rotated text on Visual Layer in WPF but as you see in the image below, the rotated text is rather blurry in some areas of the image..

Is there any option I can use to improve this? The **Arial** font is used for the text.

[image]

```
public class BeamTextDrawing : FrameworkElement
{
    private readonly VisualCollection _visuals;
    public BeamTextDrawing(double scale)
    {
        if (scale <= 0)
        {
            scale = 1;
        }
        var typeface = Settings.BeamTextTypeface;
        var cultureinfo = Settings.CultureInfo;
        var flowdirection = Settings.FlowDirection;
        var textsize = Settings.BeamTextSize / scale;
        var beamtextcolor = Settings.InPlanBeamTextColor;

        _visuals = new VisualCollection(this);

        foreach (var beam in Building.BeamsInTheElevation)
        {
            var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
            using (var dc = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
            {
                var text = Convert.ToString(beam.Section.Id);
                //text = scale.ToString();
                var ft = new FormattedText(text, cultureinfo, flowdirection,
                                            typeface, textsize, beamtextcolor)
                {
                    TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
                };

                var x1 = beam.ConnectivityLine.I.X;
                var y1 = beam.ConnectivityLine.I.Y;
                var x2 = beam.ConnectivityLine.J.X;
                var y2 = beam.ConnectivityLine.J.Y;

                var v1 = new Point(x2, y2) - new Point(x1, y1);
                var v2 = new Vector(1, 0);

                var hwidth = textsize;
                var l = Geometrics.GetOffset(x1, y1, x2, y2, hwidth + 5/scale);

                var angle = Vector.AngleBetween(v1, v2);
                var x = 0.5 * (l.X1 + l.X2);
                var y = 0.5 * (l.Y1 + l.Y2);

                var r = new RotateTransform(angle, x, SelectableModel.FlipYAxis(y));
                dc.PushTransform(r);
                dc.DrawText(ft, SelectableModel.FlipYAxis(x, y));
            }
            _visuals.Add(drawingVisual);
        }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return _visuals[index];
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get
        {
            return _visuals.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Here is the image after using this code:

```
TextOptions.SetTextFormattingMode(this, TextFormattingMode.Display);
```

I'm still getting blurry results. Look at the middle beam text at the lower part of the image.

[image]

Comment: Could you may show some code?

Comment: @thefiloe I updated the question with code.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the [`TextFormattingMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textformattingmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to prevent blurry text:

```
public BeamTextDrawing(double scale)
{
    TextOptions.SetTextFormattingMode(this, TextFormattingMode.Display);
    // .. Your other code
```

Comment: Thanks Reed, I applied this and updated the question with the resulting image. I'm still getting blurry texts. Maybe I'm missing something very obvious here?

Comment: @Vahid you could also try `TextOptions.SetTextRenderingMode(this, TextRenderingMode.Aliased);`.  Does that help?

Comment: I've tried all of these but the result is surprisingly the same. Drawing the geometry of the text `dc.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Lime, new Pen(), ft.BuildGeometry(SelectableModel.FlipYAxis(x,y)));` solves the problem but it is very very expensive.